# Terraform - Can't access attributes on a primitive-typed value (string) when trying to add multiple disks

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I'm a total newbie to Terraform and loving it so far. However, I'm a bit stuck with the below. I'm trying to add a disk to multiple machines using a dynamic block, but I'm getting the error 'Can't access attributes on a primitive-typed value (string)' whenever I run terraform plan. The config for my compute engine instance/disk looks like this:

```
resource "google_compute_instance" "vm_instance" {
  count        = 2
  name         = "test-instance${count.index + 1}"
  machine_type = "e2-micro"
  labels = {
    "environment" = var.environment
  }

  boot_disk {
    initialize_params {
      image = var.image
    }
  }

  network_interface {
    # A default network is created for all GCP projects
    network = "default"
  }

  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
      resource_policies,
      metadata,
      attached_disk
    ]
  }

}

resource "google_compute_disk" "default" {
  for_each = toset(google_compute_instance.vm_instance.*.id)
  
  name = each.value.name
  type = "pd-ssd"
  labels = {
    environment = "dev"
  }
  physical_block_size_bytes = 4096
}

resource "google_compute_attached_disk" "default" {
  for_each = google_compute_instance.vm_instance.*.id
  disk     = google_compute_disk.default[each.key].id
  instance = each.key
}
```

It looks like the plan picks up two instances of the VM as expected, but Terraform is unable to access any of its attributes...

> │ Error: Unsupported attribute
> │
> │   on main.tf line 50, in resource "google_compute_disk" "default":
> │   50:   name = each.value.id
> │     ├────────────────
> │     │ each.value is "projects/blah/zones/europe-west2-a/instances/test-instance2"

Can anyone advise on where I'm going wrong, please? Thanks

Comment: I think it is because you are trying to use `count` and `for_each` interchangeably.

Comment: Thanks for the hint - it's working now. I've replaced for_each with count and all is well. I'm not sure which best to use, so will review that.

Comment: It always depends, I lean a bit more towards using `for_each`, but it's a usually a matter of preference.

Comment: There are cases where count is warranted and cases where for_each is warranted. When you need to use properties from objects for_each is great, and count with count index is outdated.

Comment: Also, you are not showing the part of the code generating the error. There is no `name = each.value.id` here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use [for_each](https://www.terraform.io/language/meta-arguments/for_each) over a set of string, you don't get access to properties, so this won't work.

```
resource "google_compute_disk" "default" {
  for_each = toset(google_compute_instance.vm_instance.*.id)
  
  name = each.value.name
  # ...
}
```

If you want to use each of those id's, what you need is the set key.

```
resource "google_compute_disk" "default" {
  for_each = toset(google_compute_instance.vm_instance.*.id)
  
  name = each.key
  # ...
}
```

Also, you're better off not using the [Legacy Splat Expressions](https://www.terraform.io/language/expressions/splat#legacy-attribute-only-splat-expressions), and will find the code more intuitive I suspect formed something like this:

```
resource "google_compute_disk" "default" {
  for_each = google_compute_instance.vm_instance
  
  name = each.value.id
  # ...
}
```